# Custom Role Provider web.config Error

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm using custom role provider class named "MyProvider.cs" in classes folder.
it's namespace is : Niksms.Classes

my web.config:

```
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
   <providers>
   <clear/>
   <add name="MyProvider" type="Niksms.Classes.MyProvider"/>
   </providers>
   </roleManager>
```

when I run website It gives me following error:

configuration error
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Niksms.Classes.MyProvider'.

Source Error:

```
 <add name="MyProvider" type="Niksms.Classes.MyProvider"/>
```

Help plz

update: I'm using Asp.net 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved This simple problem by moving "MyProvider.cs" to App_Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the assembly name int the "type" value:

```
<add name="MyProvider" type="Niksms.Classes.MyProvider, Niksms"/>
```

Or, if Niksms is a signed assembly, use the Assembly Qualified Name:

```
<add name="MyProvider" type="Niksms.Classes.MyProvider, Niksms, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=480814455f5ac6d4"/>
```

Both cases assume `Niksms` is name of the assembly that contains the MyProvider class.

To get the AssemblyQualifiedName use `typeof(MyProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName`.

Comment: Where should I use the "typeof(MyProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName" I'm pretty new in asp.net sorry